# Show results based on the searchstring in ASP.net core

Tags: c#, search, asp.net-core

I have a list named models which contains another list inside it named variants. I want to perform getbysearchString method where variant names are filtrerd with searchstring passed in the url.

Repository.cs

```
_list.Add(new ModelSearch
            {
                ID = 1,
                Title = "Scorpio",
                Variants=new List<Variant> { new Variant {ID=1,ModelID=1,Title="Scorpio VLX refresh" },
                    new Variant { ID=2,ModelID=1,Title="Scorpio LX refresh" },
                    new Variant { ID=3,ModelID=1,Title="Scorpio3 S2" }
                }

            });

            _list.Add(new ModelSearch
            {
                ID = 2,
                Title = "Bolero",
                Variants = new List<Variant> { new Variant {ID=1,ModelID=2,Title="T4" },
                    new Variant { ID=2,ModelID=2,Title="T4+" },
                    new Variant { ID=3,ModelID=2,Title="T6" },
                    new Variant { ID=3,ModelID=2,Title="T6+" }
                }
            });
//Search method
 public IEnumerable<ModelSearch> GetBySearchString(string searchString)
        {
            return _list.Where(m => m.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchString)|| m.Variants.Contains(searchString)).AsEnumerable();
        }
```

**ModelSearchController.cs**

```
public class ModelSearchController : Controller
    {

        private IRepository _repo;


        public ModelSearchController()
        {
            _repo = new Repository.Repository();
        }

        public IActionResult Search(string searchString)
        {
            var filteredList = _repo.GetBySearchString(searchString);
            return View(filteredList);
        }
    }

Here is my **Index.cshtml** file:

@model IEnumerable<myApp.Models.ModelSearch>

<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @foreach (var variant in item.Variants)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => variant.Title)
                    </td>


                </tr>
            }
        }
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: What does your code do now? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: I am only able to filter with respect to model names. I wan to filter the list with respect to variant names. I pass the searchstring as a url parameter.
For example, If I pass T6 as searchstring then I want variant names T6 and T6+ to be printed on screen

Comment: searchString should also be lowered, otherwise your strings may be in different cases

Comment: Converted searchstring to lower but it doesn't worked

Comment: @nff could you please elaborate on what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Here I am applying searchstring on Variants List instead of Title element in variant list. That's why it didn't work. But how to apply searchstring on list element

Answer (score 0):

Your linq query is incorrect. It just lower the case of the title, but not for searchString. Also, it didn't check the title of variants

```
public IEnumerable<ModelSearch> GetBySearchString(string searchString)
{
    return _list.Where(
        m => m.Title.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
        m.Variants.Any(v => v.Title.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    ).AsEnumerable();
}
```

**UPDATED - filter out variants that title does not contain the searchString**

```
public IEnumerable<ModelSearch> GetBySearchString(string searchString)
{
    return _list.Where(
        m => m.Title.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
        m.Variants.Any(v => v.Title.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    )
    .Select( m =>
        new ModelSearch
        {
            ID = m.ID,
            Title = m.Title,
            Variants = m.Variants.Where(v => v.Title.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList()
        }
    )
    .AsEnumerable();
}
```

Comment: It is correct upto some extent but I am getting irrelevant results.
For example, I passed search string as searchString=4. I am getting all the results corresponding to that model list. Please see this image:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=16mKeBFfshL9MgvcL2AjPHxJ2JKJ1Qbj4

Comment: hmm.. just tested the function the function returns the model "Bolero" only. Are you sure the "4" is really pass into the function?

Comment: Yes, the whole bolero model is returned with the present function. I want to return only particular row which contains 4. I don't want whole bolero model. Can we achieve that?

Comment: It doesn't work as well. It is returning the results when there is a match in both model name and variant name. It does not return the row when variant name is matched but model name is not matched.

Comment: If I input 6, it returns these 2 rows that model name is not match

Parameter: 6
ID: 2           Title: Bolero           Variants: T6
ID: 2           Title: Bolero           Variants: T6+

Comment: Try to input b, It is the name of the model. row corresponding to bolero is not printed on screen. So model name validation fails here

Comment: since it returns a model that without variant, and your view did't handle that, it shows nothing.

may be you can check if `item.Variants.Count == 0`, then shows the model id and name